# I would like to understand the logic behind the output

Tags: c, if-statement, curly-braces

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int value = 0 ;

    if(value)
    
    printf("0");
    printf("1");
    printf("2");

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is `12`
but when I tweak the code by adding curly brackets the output differs

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int value = 0 ;

    if(value)
    {
    printf("0\n");
    printf("1\n");
    printf("2\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After adding curly brackets I didn't get an output.

When I change the declared variable to `1` I expected the program to only output the line printf("2") because when the `value = 0 it gave 12` as the output excluding the first printf statment, So I expected changing the assigned variable `value = 1` as the output would exclude both the first and second printf statments, but it didn't. This made me more confused.

Summary:
If there is no curly bracket{} in the code it gives a different output for the same code with curly brackets
When I declare value=1 or any other number program prints `012`(in both codes).
I would like to know why is this happening.

Thank you.

Comment: `if` applies to the next statement only. If the next statement happens to be a `{}` - enclosed block, it will apply to that block.

Comment: Um, `if` is not `switch`.  You said "I expected changing the assigned variable value = 1 as the output would exclude both the first and second printf statments".  Not sure where you got that idea.

Comment: @SteveSummit in the code int n=4; printf(n+"goodbye") the output is bye , So I thought when value =0 it exludes the first statement then when the value is increased by 1 it should exclude another statement as well....

Comment: @MasterShahaam Okay.  If you write `printf(n+"goodbye")` that's completely different, that's pointer arithmetic. I hope you know this now, but that has nothing to do with `if` statements, or the way C handles true/false.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers. It was really helpful. Now I understand the reasons behind the outputs. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see

```
if ( condition )
    stuff
```

it means "if `condition` is true, do `stuff`".  But you have to be clear on what the `condition` is, and what the `stuff` is.

In C, the `condition` can be any expression, any expression at all.  It can be a number like `0`, or a variable like `value`, or a more complicated expression like `i > 1 && i < 10`.  And, super important: the interpretation of the value is that 0 means "false", and anything else — *any* other value at all — means "true".

And then, what about the `stuff`?  You can either have one statement, or several statements enclosed in curly braces `{ }`.
If you have one statement, the `if( condition )` part controls whether you do that one statement or not.  If you have several statements enclosed in `{ }`, the `if( condition )` part controls whether you do that whole block or not.

So when you said

```
if(value)
printf("0");
printf("1");
printf("2");
```

you had one statement — just one — controlled by the `if`.  If `value` was 0, it would not print `0`.
If `value` was anything other than 0, it would print `0`.
And then, it would always print `2` and `3`, no matter what.
That's confusing to look at, which is why people always say that proper indentation is important — if you had written it as

```
if(value)
    printf("0");
printf("1");
printf("2");
```

then the indentation would have accurately suggested the actual control flow.

And then when you said

```
if(value)
    {
    printf("0\n");
    printf("1\n");
    printf("2\n");
    }
```

now all three statements are in a block, so they're all controlled by the `if`.
If `value` was 0, it won't print anything.
If `value` was anything other than 0, it will print all three.

Answer (score 1):

In c an int can be evaluated `true` if the value is not `0` otherwise it is ecaluated as `false`. Additionally as mentioned in the comments, `if` statements without brakets only apply to the next statement, which is why your output differs there.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
if(value)

printf("0");
printf("1");
printf("2");
```

is interpreted as

```
if(value)
{
  printf("0");
}

printf("1");
printf("2");
```

`printf("0");` will be executed if `value` is non-zero; `printf("1");` and `printf("2");` will be executed unconditionally.

In the code

```
if(value)
{
printf("0\n");
printf("1\n");
printf("2\n");
}
```

all three `printf` statements will be executed only if `value` is non-zero.